# ReSharper 5.0 VS CodeRush 10.1 - Specific Feature Comparison

Tags: c#, resharper, coderush, resharper-5.0

I'm deciding between ReSharper 5.0 VS CodeRush 10.1.  I've seen a lot of questions that target which one is better/faster than the other.  For Example, ReSharper may be a little slower than CodeRush when working with large projects.  What I am looking for is a list of which features are completely, outright missing in the opponent.

An example would be that ReSharper has an intellisense replacement, which CodeRush leaves to VisualStudio.

What features does one have that the other is missing - assuming performance/speed and learning curve is a non-issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am personally using and loving both, DevExpress CodeRush Express for VS (free) and ReSharper (open source license).

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/buy/opensource_license.html

Honestly speaking I want both, though they do have some overlaps such as refactoring, code analysis. But they do have a lot of unique features, such as structure highlight (CR). And at some extent installing both consumes more system resources. However, the benefits from both products are huge.

Always use a powerful machine (or machines) as your development environment, and it can overcome a lot of pains in the near future :)

Comment: Thanks! CodeRush Express is the free version, right?  I have only tried the CR full version with Refactor!, but if the express edition has the highlighting and metrics, then I think the combination of the two is a good solution.

Comment: Yes, CodeRush Express is free and has limited features.

Answer (score 8):

(I'm ReSharper Product Manager, take with care)

For me it is not specific features that make most sense here, you can make up any numbers on comparison charts by categorizing things, e.g. you can count formatting actions as refactorings. Also some missing features here and there can be complimented with other plugins - being them within tool's ecosystem or VS ecosystem.

What I really find important for any tool of this kind is deep and accurate **code understanding**. Some tools, [unfortunately](http://dicky-programmingjoy.blogspot.com/2010/05/my-1st-code-rush-experience-can-i-code.html), are not that accurate. Every product has bugs and issues, of course, but being not able to accurately resolve symbols is show-stopper for me. May be not for other people, who value fast typing over accurate analysis and refactoring. Other tools in this area cannot even parse C# code sometimes, not to say about resolving generic overloaded methods with lambdas and correctly supporting LINQ patterns.

As for complete, direct and independent feature list comparison, I don't think there is one. I believe every product has comparison chart with Visual Studio ([ReSharper has](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/comparisonMatrix_R5.html)), so you can combine them, and then clarify specific points with the community and users of corresponding products.

Comment: +1 for the Thanks for the "unfortunately" link.  That's exactly what I was looking for - features that if you switched to the other that you couldn't live without.  I'm also seeing that ReSharper seems to be your best bet when working with an existing code base, and CR seems best if you 1) already know CR and 2) are writing code from scratch.

Comment: How long can you write code from scratch? :) When you have even dozen of types, you start navigating and changing them.

Comment: I've run into similar incorrect code understanding problems. Sometimes CodeRush breaks code when it refactors. Sometimes it crashes when you undo one of its refactorings.

Answer (score 5):

Cards on Table: I'm a huge CodeRush fan and a member of DX-Squad (Which means I help out on the DX forums)

As you might imagine, I use CodeRush quite a bit and I have a reasonably good knowledge on what is, and what isn't possible using the current DX toolset. I think however that there are few who are particularly well versed in both products

As for what might be missing from each. Typically this doesn't bother me... If I need something not supplied with CodeRush, I tend to build it myself :)

The DXCore (free framework on which CodeRush and CodeRush XPress are built) makes this very easy. Feel free to head over to [our community site](http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/) and take a look.